# Which is better using Cursor or call an Stored procedure multiple times

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

Suppose that you want to insert multiple values in a table. Before and after each insert there must be done some dependent actions so all of this procedure must be done in a single transaction. Now suppose that every inserted row dependent actions is dependent to prior committed inserts. Now which scenario is better:

1. iterate over inserting values at program level and call an Stored Procedure each time (MySQL server and application are installed in different machines)
2. using cursors with inner transaction and commit
3. using while loops
4. other scenarios

Comment: write a stored procedure for your insert statement. Do everything dependent on that insert statement in that stored procedure. Thus, you are doing everything in one transaction. And you should provide problem with some sample data so that one can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would consider **building up** a [single insert query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) of the form

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name 
(a,b,c) 
VALUES
(1,2,3)
,(4,5,6)
,(7,8,9);
```

And building that in code if you can't pass the set of data to stored proc for a single insert. There seems to be number of examples here on SO for different languages (Edit: Including in SQL)

Edit: To answer comment.
No I did understand. What I was implying was that you build this up in code first (using any prior commited data, and/or the new data that is to be inserted). In my opinion you should avoid multiple calls to the SQL DB unless it becomes a needed optimisation, as the single transaction will lock the data (dependant upon your choice of isolation level of course). The sample is just to show what the final sql would boil down to. Does that make sense?

Comment: Seems that you have not understood my question this type of insert is simple and does not relay on dependencies and side effects.

Answer (score 0):

None of them are going to be brilliant. SQL is not really designed for that sort of processing. Triggers are a possibility, but that could end up being a lot messier than any of the above solutions. Unless the loop was very simple e.g. an integer, I'd probably go with a cursor myself.

There might be ways round it, but that would depend on the exact processing you want to do and probably our own preferences